# "Sandbox" Google Analytics for security

Tags: security, google-analytics

By including Google Analytics in a website (specifically the Javascript version) isn't it true that you are giving Google complete access to all your cookies and site information?  (ie. it could be a security hole).

Can this be mitigated by putting Google in an iFrame that is sandboxed?  Or maybe only passing Google the necessary information (ie. browser type, screen resolution, etc)?

How can someone get the most out of Google Analytics without leaving the entire site open?

Or perhaps passing the data through my own server and then uploading it to Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scriptless implementation via the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) (for Universal Analytics enabled properties). This not only avoids any security issues with the script (although I'd rather trust Google on that), it also means you have more control what data is submitted to the Google Server.

Comment: Measurement protocol seems to have promise, can I get all the same analytics data this way?  Also, what do you mean "I'd rather trust Google on that"?

Comment: Just bad grammar, I meant I prefer to trust Google (since much of my daily work depends on Google products). You can do everything with the measurement protocol (support to pass the users IP for geolocation has  been announcend recently) but of course you have to collect the values yourself and pass them as parameters to the API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

A script run on your site can read cookies on your site, yes. And that data can be sent back to google, yes. That is why you shouldn't store sensitive information in cookies.  You shouldn't do this even if you don't use google analytics. Even if you don't use ANY other code except your own. Browsers and browser addons can also read that stuff and you definitely cannot control that. Again, ***never*** store sensitive information in cookies.

As far as access to "site information".. javascript can be used to read the content on your pages, know urls of pages, etc.. IOW anything you serve up on a web page. Anything that is not behind a wall (e.g. login barrier) is surely up for grabs. But crawlers will look at that stuff anyway.  Stuff *behind* walls can still be grabbed automatically, depending on what they have to actually do to get past those walls (e.g. simple registration/login barriers are pretty easy to get past).

This is also why you should never display sensitive information even in content of your site. E.g. credit card numbers, passwords, etc.. that's why virtually every site you go to that has even remotely sensitive information always shows a mask (e.g. **** ) instead of actual values.

Google Analytics does not actively do these things, but you're right: there's nothing stopping them from doing it, and you've already given them the right to do it by using their script.

And you are right: the safest way to control what Google can actually see is to send server-side requests to them.  And also put all your content behind barriers that cannot be easily crawled or scraped. The strongest barrier being one that involves having to pay for access.  People are ingenious about making bots about making crawlers and bots to get past all sorts of forms and "human" checks etc.. and you're fighting a losing battle on that count, but nothing stops a bot faster than requiring someone to give you money to access your stuff.  Of course, this also means you'd have to make *everybody* pay for access...

Anyways.. if you're that paranoid about this stuff, why use GA at all? Use something you host yourself (e.g. Piwik).  This won't solve for crawlers/bots, obviously, but it will solve for worries about GA grabbing more than you want it to.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response.  Are you saying never store sessionIDs in cookies?  Where would you store it?  Wouldn't using a secure HttpOnly cookie be pretty secure? (pretty secure since there is no such thing as definitely secure)

Comment: Also, by sensitive information, I mean the user's score, email address, images, etc. not credit card numbers.  This stuff by definition has to be displayed, its the reason the user uses the service.